# Gaining root privileges in SCO

Tags: permissions, root, sco

I am learning Linux for work, so am still a bit rusty on the edges.

I need to change the folder permission of the directory `/opt`, and I know in Linux, you do the following:

```
chmod 775 /opt
```

I get a message under that saying:

```
chmod: WARNING: cannot change /opt/: Operation not permitted (error 1).
```

Does that mean I need sudo permissions? But the `sudo` command is not recognized.

But in SCO, it is different, as SCO is a little older than Ubuntu.

I have found this link on the net, but don't quite understand what they mean by "memo": [Changing file permissions](http://osr507doc.sco.com/en/OSUserG/_Changing_file_permissions.html).

Is there an easier way of doing this, like something similar to Linux?

Comment: "memo" is simply a placeholder file name - it has no special meaning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That message means you don't have sufficient privileges on the system to change the mode of the directory. If `sudo` is not installed on the system, you will need to gain elevated privileges using `su` (you'll need the root password), when you will be able to use `chmod` in exactly the way you would on Linux - using either absolute or symbolic permissions.

If you don't have the root password, you will need to ask someone who has sufficient privileges to make the change for you. Depending on local policy, a request to have `sudo` installed and configured may or may not work.

**EDIT**

From an answer to your other [open thread](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/42950/change-owner-of-folder-in-sco), it seems that SCO has a command called `asroot`, which serves a similar purpose to `sudo` elsewhere.

Answer (score 1):

You need superuser priviledges. If you are familiar with `sudo`, then use  `asroot` and `tfadmin` for SCO OpenServer and SCO unixware, respectively.