# Change Owner of Folder in SCO

Tags: chown, sco

How can I change the Owner/group of a folder in SCO?

I did:

```
ls -l
```

and got the following:

```
...
drwxr-xr-x 9 root root 512 Jul 2 10:09 opt
...
```

I have tried:

```
chown /opt
```

But that hasn't worked.

The user I am wanting to use is: test

I have asked another question (different thread) about how to change the folder permissions, but realized I still won't be able to create folders in the /opt folder with root being the owner and group - if test is not part of the root group.

[Gaining root privileges in SCO](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/42947/change-folder-permissions-in-sco)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you read the manual? I don't have SCO but I presume `chown` works as in oridnary unix:

```
SYNOPSIS
       chown [OPTION]... [OWNER][:[GROUP]] FILE...

DESCRIPTION
       [...] If  only a colon is given, or if the entire operand is empty, nei‐
       ther the owner nor the group is changed.
```

So try

```
chown test /opt
```

In case you want to change the group also, use

```
chown test:testgroup /opt
```

Comment: I have just tried 'chown test /opt' and got this message below it: "chown: cannot change owner ID of /opt: Operation not permitted (error 1)"

Comment: You need to be root in order to be able to do the operation. Or use `asroot` (sudo equivalent of SCO)

Comment: ...or `tfadmin` if you're actually in SCO unixware.

Comment: Thank you, I had to "log out" as the test user and log in as the root, and have managed to change the owner there, now will try again.

Answer (score -1):

You can change the owner for any folder like this

```
sudo chown -R username:username Dir name
```

Comment: This does not just change owner/group of both `Dir` and `name`, but also the owner/group of every file and directory under both directories `Dir` and `name` (of course assuming both are directories).